# Crash in Test React Jest when testing an input with onFocus to change an attibute

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

My Component have a field like this:

```
         <Form.Label>E-mail</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              data-testid="inputemail"
              type="email"
              onFocus={() => setAttribute(false)}
              readOnly={attribute}
              placeholder="Enter e-mail"
            />
          </Form.Group>
```

And I tried to pass this test:

```
        it("should change 'Email' input value", async () => {
          render(<LoginPage />);
          const textVariable = ""; 
          const inputemail = screen.getByTestId("inputemail");

          inputemail.focus();
          fireEvent.input(inputemail, { target: { value: textVariable } });
          expect(inputemail).toHaveFocus(); //passing now

          await waitFor(() => {
            expect(inputemail.innerHTML).toBe(textVariable);
          });
        });
```

Test passed ok, but I get this warning:

[image]

What can I do? What is the issue, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `act` error is saying that you are trying to access the component when it is not in stable state. Your `onFocus` is changing internal state of the component so the test needs to wait until it is `rerendered`.

Try to do the following, replace this:

```js
inputemail.focus();
fireEvent.input(inputemail, { target: { value: textVariable } });
expect(inputemail).toHaveFocus(); //passing now
```

with this:

```js
inputemail.focus();
await waitFor(() => expect(inputemail).toHaveFocus());
fireEvent.input(inputemail, { target: { value: textVariable } });
```

or instead of using `fireEvent` use the [@testing-library/user-event](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event) library which [should focus](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/main/src/utility/type.ts) the field when using the `type` method.

```js
await userEvent.type(inputemail, textVariable);
```

Just remember that `user event` lib API is async.